# SVG - raphael: storing last path selected so element data can be changed

Tags: svg, path, raphael, element

[The current state](http://danu2.it.nuigalway.ie/09101916/trazoo/stack/)

As from my link you can pick different regions on the map and everything seems to be working until you re-select a county you have selected before. Data values stored with each path decide if it `isSelected` or `notSelected`. I have no problem in changing the element data just clicked with `this` but I can't find a way of storing the last element selected in a way that I can change it's element data. Which means I first have to click on the previous county to set it's element data to `notSelected`

First I define `var currentcountyselected = "";`. This allows me to store the `paths[arr[this.id]].name;`. When I click on a new path I can make the last path fill change with `$('#'+currentcountyselected).attr({fill: attributes.fill});`

In Raphael's for loop I set `obj.data('selected', 'notSelected');` so all path elements are set to `notSeelected`.

So what I need is some way to store the last path so I can change it's element data

This is the click function cleaned up from live example.

```
obj.click(function(){
if(this.data('selected') == 'notSelected')
    {this.animate({fill: '#698B22'  }, 300);                
    this.data('selected', 'isSelected');
    $('#'+currentcountyselected).attr({fill: attributes.fill}); 
    paths[arr[this.id]].value = "isSelected";
    currentcountyselected = paths[arr[this.id]].name;
    }
else
    {this.animate({fill: '#32CD32'}, 300);                  
    paths[arr[this.id]].value = "notSelected"; /* set path value*/
    this.data('selected', 'notSelected');                       
    }   
});/* end mark selections */
```

I've been working on this project for a while and the client now wants the interface to work differently. This has really ate up my hourse.

---

EDIT:
Although I have found a solution by simply taking out the `if/else` I would still like to know how to get at element data in a previous path (or any path for that matter).

Comment: I'm probably not seeing the complication correctly, but why don't you just store lastcountyselected and update it's value with the present value for currentcountyselected just before you update currentcountyselected with the new value. Then you have an easy handle to modify the last thing you'd clicked.

Comment: @amadan hi, it was complicated as it's dealing with SVG object paths.  I got it to work as I wanted with something very similar as your suggestion: on click
`paths[previouscountyselected].value = "notSelected";
paths[arr[this.id]].value = "isSelected";`
The trouble was to work out how to get at the data in each svg object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, posted as it might help someone. **The link in my question has problems with click happy users.**

---

Globals

```
var previouscountyselected = "Mayo"; /* default start, can be any county(path) */
var start = true;
var past = null;
```

Changed code

```
obj.click(function(){
if(paths[arr[this.id]].value == 'notSelected')
    {
    this.animate({fill: '#698B22'}, 200);
    paths[previouscountyselected].value = "notSelected";
    paths[arr[this.id]].value = "isSelected";
    previouscountyselected = paths[arr[this.id]].name;

    if (!start && past != this)
        {
            past.animate({ fill: '#fff' }, 200);
        }
    past = this;
    start = false;                  
}
else if(paths[arr[this.id]].value == 'isSelected')
{
    this.animate({fill: '#32CD32'}, 200);
    paths[arr[this.id]].value = "notSelected"; /* set path value */ 
}
});
```

Overview
`if (!start && past != this)` is a little unusual and is required or animated fades get messed up and choppy. The fade is not triggered if it is the first time a path is clicked and if you just hammer clicks on one path it doesn't fade to white. The main **if/else** handles the actual control value.
Until I get a jsfiddle up this link will demonstrate the desired behaviour.

---

**Note!** the drop menu in this link does not work.

[Click happy friendly](http://danu2.it.nuigalway.ie/09101916/trazoo/stack/solution/)